# How to cast the first view of a uinavigationview controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been following a firebase tutorial to create my own chat application, I am trying to access a chatviewcontroller from the uiviewcontroller containing a table view. The Viewcontroller is embedded in a navigation controller. How can I bring up the chatviewcontroller when a cell is selected?

Here is my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    //retrieve the destination view controller
    let navVc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController

    let channelVc = navVc.viewControllers.chatViewController as! ViewController

    // set the senderDisplayName in Viewcontroller to the email provided in the email field by the user

    channelVc.senderDisplayName = userEmailTextField?.text
}
```

[Here is the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUOhZ.png)

Comment: I would strongly recommend properly using optionals rather than force-unwrapping with no qualification.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `ChatViewController` is the root view controller of your navigation controller you should change your code to this:

```
let channelVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! ChatViewController
```

`navVC.viewControllers` is an array of the `UIViewController`s managed by that `UINavigationController`, so that array would not have a property called `chatViewController` unless you implemented something custom.

EDIT: To put it all together, and also to demonstrate how to safely unwrap these optionals, your `prepareForSegue` should look like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if let navVc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let channelVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as? ChatViewController {
        //Now you have a reference to your ChatVC, and you can set the DisplayName
        channelVc.senderDisplayName = userEmailTextField?.text
    }
}
```

Comment: What file would i implement this? View controller (containing the table view, embedded in a navigation controller) or login view controller (segues to view controller once authenticated)?

Comment: @NnamdiAffia I added an edit to show you exactly where do this.  You were very close in your original implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it still crashes when i select a cell. i have edited my post to show the error msg. please help

Comment: I'd need to see a LOT more code and storyboard setup to know what's happening.  When it crashes you need to scroll to the top of the debugger crash code to see what the actual error message is.  Your screenshot shows only the bottom, so I don't see any helpful info.

Comment: it works!!!!!!! Chatviewcontroller isn't the root, view controller is. i just replaced chatviewcontroller with viewcontroller in your edit! You're a genius, rock on!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the first view controller from the `UINavigationController`:

```
let channelVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! ChatViewController
```

Comment: i have tried that several times but it keeps crashing when i select a cell. I think it is because i have several other view controllers on the storyboard. Also i have embedded the view controller in a navigation controller then connected a segue from the cell to chatviewcontroller.